# Missing Module in gulpfile 'clone-stats'

Tags: ionic-framework, npm, gulp, npm-install

I am working with ionic and my ionic build android command isn't working.
The error message I get is "Uh oh! Looks like you're missing a module in your gulp file:  Cannot find module 'clone-stats'
Do you need to run 'npm install'?

I highlighted my steps in the image below:

[image]

I have no idea what 'clone-stats' is and why it is missing.  It was working yesterday.

I have tried to reinstall ionic.  I tried npm install -g.  I tried removing and adding the android platform back.  ionic serve gives me the same error.

I am not familiar with gulp.  Does anybody know the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have required to install 'clone-stats' module.

- open terminal
- go to your project folder and type `npm install clone-stats`.
- if you facing permission error then use `sudo npm install clone-stats`

  hope it's work for you..

Comment: I ended up just doing a 'ionic start temp blank' and making a completely new project and replaced the www folder with all my code.  It seems to work now.  I will try your solution if I run into that problem again.  Thanks for your help.